# How to get all users who comment and set like using facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Tell me how you can get all the users who left a comment or like on my photo using graph.facebook.com.

If I understand the documentation correctly, it is already impossible to do this at the moment.
Is it so?

Comment: I think you should still be able to get the amount of likes, and the message content of the comments. You will however not get any user details, unless the users have granted your app permission to access their basic details.

Comment: I try https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ for test requests, so if i use
https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/2807002372727953_1252319421529597/likes
I see only mine likes

Answer (score -2):

Open your facebook home page. Right click on it and select inspect. Press ctrl+f to find tra. After you alick tra it will redirect you the list of people who have commented on your profile and photos.

Comment: The question is about getting this info via API, not about using the Facebook UI.